# How should i name the .php file to show custom posts under a taxonomy's term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

Taxonomy name : brands

Custom post types (3) : watches, jewelries, accessories

Right now the taxonomy "brands" has only one term and that is "rolex". I have used rewrite so the url is like that :

```
www.mysite.com/watches/rolex/my_posts_title
```

*First is custom post's type, then taxonomy's name, then post's title.

I have created a template which i want to show all the custom post types of the specific brand but can't make it work. (rolex in that case)

For example right now i want to hit the below url:

```
www.mysite.com/watches/rolex
or
www.mysite.com/jewelry/rolex
or
www.mysite.com/accessories/rolex
or
www.mysite.com/watches/gucci (another brand)
```

How should i name this template php file so when i hit one of the above links to make it work? I have tried different things but i can't find the solution - is the rewrite i used causing any problems?

Comment: There is no template solution to this, you need additional rewrite rules.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know!